# Read a File with C# from command-line

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

How I read a file from a command-line in C#?  An example command is:

```
program.exe < textfile
```

Comment: `C#` and `C`? Choose one please..

Comment: Why this is tag for `C` ?

Answer (score 2):

That is sending the file to standard input, so you can get the data stream through [the `Console.In` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.in.aspx).

Here's a quick proof of concept:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fileContents = System.Console.In.ReadToEnd();
    System.Console.Write(fileContents);
}
```

This was called on the command prompt with:

```
program.exe < file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Input/Output re-direction works for all executable independent of language.

So just read the file in normal way from standard input

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by P0W, that is a function of cmd.exe, not C#.  However, in C#, you would use the various Console.ReadXXX methods to get data from standard input.